# How to fake a 4G connection?

Tags: samsung, 9.0-pie, xposed-framework, magisk, edxposed

I need to find a way to mock 3g/4g, so applications think they are connected via data(3g/4g). But in reality, I am connected to wifi.

My device is running Android 9 (Pie) with Magisk & EdXposed.

Comment: Hello. Can you mention why you want to do that? Perhaps your original problem can be solved in a different way.

Comment: a game requires wifi for download resources, but it is useless, so he have a option for only download on Wi-Fi, so if i are connected on Wi-Fi he download, but in 4g no, so i need to mock my wifi

Comment: Have you tried existing xposed modules like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chylek.adam.fakewifi

Comment: yes, but this is for 4g to wifi, i need Wi-Fi to 4g